# CPT with its own category and tag url

Tags: custom-post-types, archive-template

I am developing a wordpress site where multiple CPT will used for top level segregation. Each CPT must have its won category and tag base. Also thew should have their own URLS to display only related CPT archive pages.

Example

Site

```
http://example.net
```

CPT: command, book

Expected Archive page URL

```
http://example.net/command  
http://example.net/command/category/category
http://example.net/command/tag/tag1


http://example.net/book 
http://example.net/book/category/category1
http://example.net/book/tag/tag1

http://example.net/command/2016/05
http://example.net/book/2016/05
```

Answer (score 1):

First, we need to declare CPT.

Here in example I am creating with the name "**command**".

Also I am adding category and tag support for this CPT.

The CPT will be public, searchable, will have archive page, feed page etc.

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );

function create_post_type() {

    $post_array =   array(
        'name'              => __( 'Command' ),
        'singular_name'     => __( 'command' )

      );
    $post_args = array(
        'labels'                => $post_array,
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Command' ),
        'taxonomies'            => array('category','post_tag'),
        'public'                => true,
        'has_archive'           => true,
        'rewrite'               => array('slug' => 'command'),
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'exclude_from_scratch'  =>false,
        'with_front'            => true,
        'feeds'                 => true,
        'supports'              => array( 'title','editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments','revisions' ),
    );
  register_post_type( 'command',$post_args);

}
```

Now I am declaring rewrite rule to have the separate URL facility for CPT category and tag.

```
http://domain.net/command/category/catname
http://domain.net/command/tag/tagname
```

will be converted to the following URLS which are understandable by wordpress.

```
http://domain.net/?page_type=command&category_name=catname
http://domain.net/?page_type=command&tag=tagname
```

So that wordpress could understand them.

```
add_action('init', 'category_cpt_rewrites');

function category_cpt_rewrites() {
    $custom_post_types = array('command'); //some example post types
    foreach ( $custom_post_types as $post_type ) {
        $rule = '^' . $post_type . '/category/(.+?)/?$';
        $rewrite = 'index.php?post_type=' . $post_type . '&category_name=$matches[1]';
        add_rewrite_rule($rule,$rewrite,'top');
    }
        foreach ( $custom_post_types as $post_type ) {
        $rule = '^' . $post_type . '/tag/(.+?)/?$';
        $rewrite = 'index.php?post_type=' . $post_type . '&tag=$matches[1]';
        add_rewrite_rule($rule,$rewrite,'top');
    }


}
```

We will also rewrite for date based archive pages like this.

```
http://example.net/command/2016/05
```

will be converted to

```
http://example.net/?post_type=command&m=201605
```

the code is as followed.

```
add_action('init', 'date_cpt_rewrites');

function date_cpt_rewrites() {
    $custom_post_types = array('command'); //some example post types
    foreach ( $custom_post_types as $post_type ) {
        $rule = '^' . $post_type . '/(\d+)/(\d+)/?$';
        $rewrite = 'index.php?post_type=' . $post_type . '&m=$matches[1]$matches[2]';
        add_rewrite_rule($rule,$rewrite,'top');
    }


}
```

Here we are making sure that our CPT "**command**" posts are available in other common archive also. 
By default post type "post" is only shown on archive pages.

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_get_posts' );

function my_get_posts( $query ) {

    if ( is_category() || is_tag() || is_search() || is_home() || is_front_page() || is_author() || is_archive() && $query->is_main_query() )
                $post_type = get_query_var('post_type');
                if($post_type) {
                    $post_type = $post_type;
                }else{
                    $post_type = array('post','command'); // replace cpt to your custom post type
                    $query->set( 'post_type', $post_type );
                }
    return $query;
}
```

So Here entire game is converting your desired URLS into wordpress understandable urls.

Comment: Would you be able to explain how your code works, so others can learn from it? See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32716/feeding-them-vs-teaching-to-fish for some background on why :)

Comment: sure sir, i have updated post with explanation. I am here to help friends.